# How to implement a SAP UI5 - Cell Formatter in ListReport Template

Tags: javascript, sapui5

We are using a List Report template from SAP UI5 template library for a Reporting application.

Now we are facing problem in formatting one particular cell data, which is coming from back-end xsodata service.

**Example**
Suppose we need to show the time in HH:MM:SS (Hour:Minute:Seconds) format and we are receiving it only in form of seconds.

We have the logic to convert seconds to hours but don't know where to plugin the formatter function.

**If it was Smarttable or the sap.m.table, we could have mentioned this in the view itself. how to do this in List Report Template?**

Any sort of help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My suggestion is get the id or class of the particular cell and use jQuery or javascript to format the value.

Comment: Yes that might be one way, but isn't it too much time consuming for a large data set ? I have more than 700 rows in the table. So to perform the operation on each cell, every time the view is getting rendered will make the application slow.

Comment: for loop for 700 or so will not make the application slow.

Comment: But, I think, that is anyway not the ideal way of doing this.

Comment: yes it is not ideal, post this question even in SCN you might find the needful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using parts , where one part will be your odata binding and in formatter use the UI5 date formatter . 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored_v1.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.TypeDateAsDate/preview

```
 <Text text="{
                path: '/this_Is_the_binding',
                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',
                formatOptions: {
                    pattern: 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss'
                }
            }" />
```

This can solve your issue. You can add pattern as per your need

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your time and effort. But unfortunately, your solution will not work for us. As I mentioned, we are using a ui5 library template not any xml views, and I suppose your solution only work in case of xml view where you can use ui5's built-in ui controls (like you used Text in your example ). In template we use annotation.xml file for rendering views. Please have a look at this - https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/16/fiori-elements-how-to-develop-a-list-report-basic-approach/

Comment: Ever found a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue - I want to display one cell as Int instead of decimal...